# filter to removed undefined items in typescript using object destructuring

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I would like to use object destructuring while still using a type guard. However, after filtering out an undefined object key, typescript still infers a undefined type.

I do not want to use non-null assertion because our linter will complain.

Eg:

```
type theDataStructure = {
 payloadKey1: string,
 payloadKey2: string,
 requiredForPayload?: string ,
 otherKeyNotNeededinPayload: string,
}

const unfilteredPayload: theDataStructure[] = getPayload()

unfilteredPayload
   .filter(({ requiredKey }) => requiredKey && arbitraryBusinessLogic(requiredKey)
   .map(({ payloadKey1, payloadKey2, requiredKey }) => sendPayLoad(payloadKey1, payloadKey2, requiredKey)
```

Typescript still has the type of requiredKey as string | undefined in the map function.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` does not change the type of the array. There should be an open issue somewhere in the TS repository requesting that type narrowing gets propagated, as this is a common use case.

```
// Still T[]:
filter(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): T[];
```